# event.preventDefault() Causing :hover pseudo class to stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a document navigation, similar to that on the Bootstrap site for their documentation. I've got it working on the whole, but there is one little aspect of it which is bugging me.

Like on Bootstrap, I am using a combination of the affix.js and scrollSpy.js, and this is working. See the following 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crickes/z32rpe3b/).

```
        $('#doc_nav').on( "click", "a", function( e ){
//            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);
            var offset = $target.offset().top;
            console.log(offset);
            offset = offset - 100;
            console.log(offset);

            $('html, body').scrollTop( offset );


        });
```

With the e.preventDefault() commented out, the behavior of the navigation menu is as expected. Scrolling down the window results in the displayed div being highlighted on the menu. Clicking on an item in the menu list, takes you directly to corresponding div on the page and when you then scroll away from that section on the page, the menu updates accordingly.

On my 'real' page, I have a fixed header of height 100px. So currently, when I click on a menu link, the pages jumps to the required section and places it at the top of the page where the header obscures it slightly. The scrollTop part of the code above doesn't seem to work unless I use e.preventDefault(). If you uncomment this line in the fiddle and run it again, click on 'Heading 3' link on the menu, and you will see that it now puts the Heading 3 content in the page offset by 100px from the top. Perfect.

However, now scroll back up the page towards the top. You will see that the 'Heading 3' list item, remains in its :hover state, even when the mouse is no where near it. Its as though the e.preventDefault() has prevented the browser from detecting that the mouse is no longer hovering on the item.

Mouseclicking anywhere outside the browser window, corrects the problem.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong here? How can I prevent the default behavior of the anchor click so I can control the page scroll placement, without stopping the correct CSS painting in the process?

The problem arises because I am preventing the browsers default behavior, using e.preventDefault(), as I want to control the scroll to the anchored element.

I've tested this in Firefox and IE10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not the `:hover` state, but the `:focus` state.

When you click on a link, that link gains focus so you apply the `:focus` styling (that is the same as the `:hover` styling in your code). By preventing the default behavior, that link stays active and doesn't lose the focus.

One quick solution would be to unfocus/blur the element by using: `$(this).blur()`.

In your code it would look like this:

```
    $('#doc_nav').on( "click", "a", function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        var offset = $target.offset().top;
        console.log(offset);
        offset = offset - 100;
        console.log(offset);
        $(this).blur();
        $('html, body').scrollTop( offset );
    });
```

You can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/z32rpe3b/30/

---

**Why did it work fine with `e.preventDefault()` but incorrectly without it?**

The answer to this has to do with the order of execution. The `onclick` event happens before the `href` redirection happens in the browser:

- Without the `e.preventDefault()`, the code is executed, and the browser scrolled correctly to the target `offset - 100` position (in the `onclick`), but then it executed the link `href` and scrolled to the target `offset`. It just happens so fast that it seems that it goes directly to the target position.
- With `e.preventDefault()`, the code is executed (scrolling to `offset - 100`), and the browser doesn't execute the `href` action (so it stays at `offset - 100`).

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Thanks. I'm kicking myself it was so easy! I was fixated on it being the :hover pseudo class, I missed the :focus. Can you answer the other part of the puzzle, why the scrollTop() didn't work unless I'd used e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: That has to do with the order in which events are executed. I updated my answer with an explanation of why that happened.